# Run mod_wsgi with pyenv

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, pyenv

I'm trying to run a python web app on Apache server.  I have installed mod_wsgi:
`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi`.

This is my site config file:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName 192.168.60.144

    WSGIDaemonProcess myapp.dev processes=1 threads=1 python-home="/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1" python-path="/home/user/API" home='/home/user/API'
    WSGIProcessGroup myapp.dev
    WSGIScriptAlias /  /home/user/API/config_files/myservice.wsgi.py

    <Directory /home/user/API>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    DocumentRoot /home/user/API/myservice/testdir
    <Directory />
         AllowOverride None
          Require all granted
     </Directory>

</virtualhost>
```

However, when trying to access the web app, I get "Internal server error". This is the error from logs:

> [Mon Mar 12 13:34:04.054636 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6762:tid 139768980616960] [remote 10.10.30.13:34438] mod_wsgi (pid=6762): Target WSGI script '/home/user/API/config_files/myservice.wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
>   [Mon Mar 12 13:34:04.054665 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6762:tid 139768980616960] [remote 10.10.30.13:34438] mod_wsgi (pid=6762): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/user/API/config_files/myservice.wsgi.py'.
>   [Mon Mar 12 13:34:04.054693 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6762:tid 139768980616960] [remote 10.10.30.13:34438] Traceback (most recent call last):
>   [Mon Mar 12 13:34:04.054717 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6762:tid 139768980616960] [remote 10.10.30.13:34438]   File "/home/user/API/config_files/myservice.wsgi.py", line 6, in 
>   [Mon Mar 12 13:34:04.054752 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6762:tid 139768980616960] [remote 10.10.30.13:34438]     from pathlib import Path
>   [Mon Mar 12 13:34:04.054775 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 6762:tid 139768980616960] [remote 10.10.30.13:34438] ImportError: **No module named pathlib**

I have checked the pyenv python installation, and it has the pathlib module installed. This means that probably, not the right version of Python is being used. How can I check which Python version is being used? Did I set the `python-home` property incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use system packaged version of mod_wsgi with a pyenv environment. It is necessary for mod_wsgi to be compiled for the specific Python installation/version being used. When using pyenv it is a separate Python installation, not the system Python that is being used. You should use the `pip install` method for installing mod_wsgi compiled for Python installation created by pyenv. Do make sure that when you had pyenv install Python that shared libraries were enabled.

- https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/392

IOW, uninstall system packaged version of mod_wsgi and then use `pip install` method to install mod_wsgi and configure Apache to use it. See:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

In particular, see the `Connecting into Apache installation` section for how to load the pip installed mod_wsgi into Apache. I.e., modifying the path in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.load` to point to the `mod_wsgi-<version>.so` file in the virtual environment.

Comment: Yes, but then how to get mod_wsgi to use the pyenv environment and not the system one that comes with Redhat in my case?   The system has 3.6 installed globally, but I'm trying to use 3.9 with pyenv.  Thanks.